# Regex matching multiple string types to search HS-Codes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the patters to detect some HS-Codes of some files I'm parsing.

I can find *three types* of strings that contains HS-Codes.

1. `1 AUTOMATION BYTRANSEXTENDED 4020.HS-CODE: 8428.9000` 
   Here I want to extract everything after `HS-CODE:` (8428.9000)
2. `RECONDHS CODE 84669400AMS REF CHS220928SCAC SSLL`.
   Here I want to get everything after `HS CODE` until a new non-numeric number arrives (84669400)
3. `============H.S.CODE: 8466.93`
   This is like the first one, get everything after `H.S CODE:` (8466.93)

The pattern `HS-CODE:\s+\K\S+` works for the 1st type, and also for the 3rd type (`H.S.CODE: \s+\K\S+`).
You can test it right here: https://regex101.com/r/iZ9lO1/1

I would like to know how can I combine the pattern in order to match on any of the three types explained above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to meet all three requirements specified in the question:

```
H\.?S[.\s-]CODE[:\s]+\K[\d.]+
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZ9lO1/3)

It is very similar to your attempted regex with some optional matching around `H` and `S` and `CODE` segments.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't fit the second string type. Instead of taking every number until the first non-numeric value `84669400`, it takes everything `84669400AMS` until the next empty space.